# Writing custom trace messages to Application Insight from Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I working on Azure Function App and would like to adding custom messages/traces which can aid in debugging and improving performance. THis is my code I am using:

```html
var telemetry = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient();
telemetry.TrackTrace("Alert Button Pressed by Device ->"+CloudObject.A, SeverityLevel.Warning,new Dictionary<string, string> { { "IoT Object", IOTMESSAGE } });
```

But when I go to Application Insight and Query traces(All) I do not see trace message I am setting.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You are using an obsolete way of getting a telemetry client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It still not working. I am getting this warning, could this be an issue?

I have set a sampling and data ap on application insight, I am hoping custom trace messages ignore those set limits

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced with the same code and got the expected results as below:

```cs
 [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
                .Value;
            var telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
            telemetry.TrackEvent("Loading HomeController-Index View");          
            telemetry.TrackTrace("Alert Button Pressed by Device ->" + CloudObject.A, SeverityLevel.Warning, new Dictionary<string, string> { { "IoT Object", IOTMESSAGE } });
            if (name == null)
            {
                // Get request body
                dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
                name = data?.name;
            }

            return name == null
                ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
                : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name);
        }
```

**Application Insights:**

[image: https://i.imgur.com/vWEqPNu.png]

**Query Traces:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You shoud not instantiate `TelemetryClient` using the parameterless constructor. Use dependency injection instead.

1. Make sure you have added the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights NuGet package
2. Make sure the instrumentation key is set (APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY)
3. Create an instance in the constructor of the function, for example:

```cs
       public HttpTrigger2(TelemetryConfiguration telemetryConfiguration)
       {
           this.telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration);
       }
```

When 1 and 2 are done you could also use the `ILogger` interface to create traces telemetry in application insights. You can inject a logger like this:

```cs
        [FunctionName("HttpTrigger2")]
        public Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)]
            HttpRequest req, ExecutionContext context, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            [..]
        }
```

Please read [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v2%2Ccmd#logging) in the docs carefully.

Comment: I can see that log.logInformation, is writing to my application Insight but not TrackEvent or TrackTrace.

My azure function is being triggered by my IoT Hub, the aim is if user has pressed a button on the IoT device . I would like to have it logged for debugging purpose.

If my logInformation is being written when its being triggered and not TrackTrace, does this give any indication on what could be wrong?

Plus i have restricted sampling and data capture to the minimum, so unessary data is ignored. Can it be set to that when i specify a particular type of log it is always written?

Comment: @user8400863 Did you create the telemetry client as I showed in #3? Can you post the updated code?

Comment: Do you mean?
this.telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration);

Comment: @user8400863 yes.

Comment: I will try to create new HTTP trigger function to test it, instead of doing it in my other process. I have set the sampling and data retention to a minium to avoid unessary data capture and costing.  If my sampling period is set to 1%, would it effect this showing up on Application Insight. The aim is to limit unessary data, and anything I need to capture  such as exception or manual trace should always be captured.  I have many IoT device, where the logs are displayed, otherwise my Application Insight will be filled with all this data, which is already saved in a Azure Table.

Comment: *If my sampling period is set to 1%, would it effect this showing up on Application Insight*- > yes it does. If you want to have fine control over what is pushed and what is not you can create your own [filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#filtering).